# Unable to get data from array

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, url, nsdata

i'm facing a problem trying to access data into an array which contain some image URL.

Each time i try to create my image, my application never stop to load, , and make a loop, by the way my array never stop to be filled.

This is my code :

```
class swipe : UIViewController, KinderDelegate {    

    var urls = [NSURL!]()
    var pictureApp: String!

    func fetchdata(int: Int, completion: (()->())?) {

         for repo in repo {
                    urls.append(NSURL(string: repo.picture_url!)!)
                    dump(repos)
                    i++
                    NSLog("nombre de line = %i", PicArray.count)

                    pictureApp = repo.picture_url
         }

        if let img = imageCache[pictureApp!] {
                    let newCard = Model()
                    newCard.image = img
                    print("image présente")
        }else {

            for url in urls{
               if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
                  let newCard = Model()
                  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
                     if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                              let image = UIImage(data: data)!
                              newCard.image = (image: image)
                              dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                        newCard.image
                              }
                     }
                  }
                  self.data.append(newCard)
               }                            
            }
       }

       if self.data.count == 4 {
          completion!()
          return
       } else {
          self.fetchData(0, completion: completion)
       }
   }

}
```

How can i exploit the URLs which are in my array to create some image ?

Comment: shouldn't it be  

`for repo in repos`

Comment: additionally to Azzaknight, where 'repos' are comming from?

Comment: Thank you guys , effectively i dont know why i just didn't used my loop "repo for repos", i tried with it and change my code as my updated code, and everything work , thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Like suggested by Azzaknight , i tried with the loop "repo for repos" and changed my code for that :

```
do {
    data = try NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: repo.picture_url!)!, options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
     let image = UIImage(data: data!)!
      newCard.image = (image: image)
       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                        newCard.image
                                    }
                                }
                                catch {
                                    print("Handle \(error) here")
                                }
                       }
              }
              self.data.append(newCard)
           }
```

Everything work now !